# Levenshtein distance "proper" range for fuzzy matching

Tags: similarities, distance-functions

I am hoping to use Levenshtein distance concept for fuzzy matching in SQL joins between two tables on `t1.first_name||last_name = t2.first_name||last_name`.

Is anyone familiar with a "magical range" (or can suggest something from experience) in which a record should fall between to be deemed a likely match? ie. what should the min and max `levenshtein (t1.first_name||last_name , t2.first_name||last_name)` be to be considered a likely match.

Comment: this will be based on your data.  If you have data that are already fuzzy-matched (maybe do a few ~1000 by hand), then you can run fuzzy-matching on them with different thresholds and see which performs best.

Comment: Nope. You should do some exploratory data analysis. It will be relevant if those joins are many-to-one versus one-to-one.